# Converting a column in data set which has time format(hms) into seconds

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column in dataset that has time format in HMS into seconds.

Below is how my dataset looks like:

```
Participant Event ID    Event_start Event_time
Joe          1               3         1:49:52
Arya         1               2         1:37:39
Cynthia      1               1         1:40:17
```

I used this

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate(Timeinsec = period_to_seconds(hms("Event_time")))
```

it gives me warning.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to see the Event_time in seconds (6592 seconds for Joe and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because `Event_time` is quoted. Try it without quotes:

```
dataset %>%
  mutate(Timeinsec = hms(Event_time))
```

If you want seconds as an integer, use `period_to_seconds`:

```
dataset %>%
  mutate(Sec = period_to_seconds(hms(Event_time)))
```